# How to check if all data loaded into DataTable in c#?

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, datatable

I have a `Datatable dt`.
I fill `dt` like this - `adapter.Fill(dt)`
I want to learn if there is an event(or a method) which
helps me to know if all data loaded into `dt`.
Like `DataBindingComplete` event for `DataGridView`.

Comment: DataTable has events that are raised while you Fill the DataTable (RowChanging and RowChanged) but there is no event triggered when the reader finish to load data. It just return from the call

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `DataTable` is null, but you can't check if all data are loaded into `dt`(this depends on which query you have done). Then, according to my knowledge, `Datatable.Fill()` is a  synchronous method.So you know it has finished because the method returns to you. If it didn't "finish", it would have thrown an exception.

Comment: the easiest way is to check if the table is null, unless your trying to subscribe to the event for multithreading purposes